# Error after adding JSON Endpoint to WCF Silverlight RIA Service

Tags: json, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am attempting to add a json endpoint to an existing WCF RIA Silverlight servive using the info found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepm/archive/2010/05/14/silverlight-tv-episode-26-exposing-soap-json-and-odata-endpoints-from-ria-services.aspx

However when I launch the project in debug I get a

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

error in Silverlight.

The WCF Trace says:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/Services/CTCT-KronosNameManagement-Web-Services-BPAuthenticationDomainService.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. ---&gt;
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)    at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)    at
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost.CreateEndpointFactoryInstance(ProviderSettings
>   provider)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2&amp;
>   implementedContracts)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type
>   serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---

If I remove the endpoint in the web config, boom: it works again... Except for the json of course.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <domainServices>
      <endpoints>
        <add name="JSON" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.JsonEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </endpoints>
    </domainServices>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I do have the WCF Ria Services Toolkit installed. The System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll version is 4.1.61829.0

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Deepesh stated clearly that you needed to add a reference to `Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll` in the write up, I don't think this was mentioned in the video and when I was troubleshooting I saw that I had a reference to `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll` and did not notice the differnece betweent he two DLLs. Adding a reference to the first fixed everything.